# Timed retry on axios failure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I am using axios in the node module that I am developing for private use. On network failure, I want to perform retries in certain intervals (like exponential backoff). I have done this in my other react-redux project using delay from redux-saga. Below is the snippet of it:

```
return dealy(500).then(() => axios(error.config))
```

I want to achieve the same thing using plain es6 or suggest me if there are any light-weight delay libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not want to use third-party library for this only purpose. I had created a custom delay method that returns promise and resolves after certain point of time. Here is the snippet for the same:

```
const delay = (timeMs) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeMs));
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) and get on top of its extra Promise features also [Promise.delay](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/delay.html).

This would allow you something similar to what you posted:

```
Promise.delay(500).then(function() {
    console.log("500 ms passed");
    return "Hello world";
}).delay(500).then(function(helloWorldString) {
    console.log(helloWorldString);
    console.log("another 500 ms passed") ;
});
```